# Invoke API Rest Call with Power BI Service Principal

Tags: azure, powershell, powerbi

I created an Azure App registration for a Power BI Service Principal. In Power BI Admin Center I enabled "Allow service principals to use Power BI APIs".

For development purposes I granted all API permissions inside Azure, although regarding Microsoft Docs `Dataset.ReadWrite.All` will be normally sufficient.

I can connect to the tenant with Powershell (App ID & Credentials)

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Tenant 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx' -Credential (Get-Credential) -ServicePrincipal
```

But after that I can't call any APIs. Even a simple GET-Method is not working, e.g:

```
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/gateways/xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/datasources' -Method GET
```

I get the following error:

> Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod : One or more errors occurred.
> At line:2 char:1
>
> - Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/gat ...
> - CategoryInfo          : WriteError:
>   (Microsoft.Power...werBIRestMethod:InvokePowerBIRestMethod) [Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod], AggregateException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : One or more errors occurred., Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Profile.InvokePowerBIRestMethod

Any ideas? Did I miss some configuration here?

Comment: You said you enabled "Allow service principals to use Power BI APIs", but didn't mentioned that you [added the service principal to a security group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#step-2---create-an-azure-ad-security-group) and [added that security group to the list bellow the toggle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#step-3---enable-the-power-bi-service-admin-settings). Did you?

Comment: Hi! Yes I added the service principal to a security group and added that group in the list

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling that too:

PowerBI > Admin Portal setting "Dataset Execute Queries REST API"

[image: PowerBI > Admin Portal setting "Dataset Execute Queries REST API"]

And also check if that service principal (or the security group that it belongs) has permissions in the powerbi workspace...